# compile error in installing TLD

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, opencv, tld

I am installing the TLD application based on the instructions shown on https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD/wiki/Installation

Using:

OpenCV 2.4.2

Matlab R2010b x 64bits

Win7 x 64

VS2010 Professional

Everything works fine until I executed this step "6) In Matlab, run compile.m"

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\extern\include\tmwtypes.h(821) : warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'wchar_t' when no variable is declared 
**c:\program files\matlab\r2011b\extern\include\matrix.h(319) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int** 
lk.cpp(39) : warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(40) : warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(146) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(146) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(155) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(155) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(162) : warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(175) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(175) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(176) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(176) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(177) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
lk.cpp(177) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data 
C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'lk.cpp' failed.
```

I have searched through many websites but to no avail. Hopefully, someone can enlighten me on this problem. All solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any error or warning on step `2.5`?

Comment: can you compile a simple MEX function first to make sure everything is set up correctly? for example try compiling `yprime.c` found in the $matlabroot/extern/examples/mex directory: `mex -largeArrayDims yprime.c`